# How to obtain a table with borders using perl?

Tags: perl

I've 2 arrays `@arr` & `@arr1` each having 10 elements stored in it.
I need to print a table with header.
I need to load these array values into table of 10 rows & 2 columns.

```
@arr values into 1st column & `@arr1` into second column.
```

Table should like something as displayed here. How can I do it in perl scripting?

[image]

Comment: [Previous version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238476/how-to-print-table-with-border-in-perl) in case you have enough rep to see it.

Comment: @ Sinan Unur : I just know to print the simple table. If you really know the solution for the above question then please proceed.

Comment: You already got the answer in my comment to your previous question: use `map` instead of putting a `for` loop in a method call. Also helpful: Read the errors `perl` gives you when you try to run your code. Also helpful: Do spend some time studying a language. I am not sure what thought process resulted in the embedded `for` loop, but it seems to me you just want someone to work for you for free.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I'm learning perl & implementing it parallel. I don't have enough idea regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge your arrays with [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). This easily extends to more columns as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Table;

my @arr = 'a' .. 'j';
my @arr1 = 1 .. 10;

my $tb = Text::Table->new("Col 1", "Col 2");
$tb->load( map [$arr[$_], $arr1[$_]], 0 .. $#arr );

print $tb;
```

Output:

```
Col 1 Col 2
a      1   
b      2   
c      3   
d      4   
e      5   
f      6   
g      7   
h      8   
i      9   
j     10
```

If you want to add borders, you can do something like this instead:

```
my $tb = Text::Table->new(
    {is_sep => 1, title => '| ', body => '| '},
    "Col 1",
    {is_sep => 1, title => ' | ', body => ' | '},
    "Col 2",
    {is_sep => 1, title => ' |', body => ' |'},
);

$tb->load(map [$arr[$_], $arr1[$_]], 0 .. $#arr);

print $tb->rule('-', '+');

for (0 .. @arr) {
    print $tb->table($_);
    print $tb->rule('-', '+');
}
```

Everything above `my $tb = ...` is unchanged. Personally I'm not a big fan of ascii borders though.

Comment: @ flesk : what does  ',0 .. $#arr' in $tb->load( map [$arr[$_], $arr1[$_]], 0 .. $#arr );  mean ?

Comment: Oh, make sure you put in the borders. OP wants **borders** ;-)

Comment: @Jackie James, range operator. creates a list of numbers. see perlop

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Added borders. Everybody loves borders. ;) Thanks for adding the link to `map`. Should answer Jackie James' question.

Comment: @ flesk & SinanÜnür: map works fine instead of for loop. Can you please review the above edited snippet for border ?

Comment: @JackieJames Your question said nothing about HTML tables. Now, you try to edit flesk's answer to generate HTML. Rejected because it was too drastic a change.

Comment: @JackieJames: Like Sinan Ünür said, your edit seemed to have little to do with the original answer. I'll give you a hint though: Replace `Tr ( td(@arr), td(@arr1))` with `map { Tr( td($arr[$_]), td($arr1[$_]) ) } 0 .. $#arr`. You definitely should read up on the basics of Perl.

Comment: @ flesk : great work. This is another way of creating it without using HTML. great wotk indeed.